# Sencha touch and Sfdc mobile sdk.. which phonegap (and which license)?

Tags: licenses, mobilesdk, salesforce-sencha

I am about to develop a mobile app (cross-device) which will use:

Sencha touch 2.3.1 and Sfdc mobile sdk 2.1

I'd need to know if the following is correct:
-I must use phonegap 2.3 because that's still the versione supported by the Sfdc mobile sdk.

Could you also find a reference where itthe sdk 2.1 -> phonegap 2.3 is? I've read and heard but I can't find an official page where this specific is written, thank you very much!

Also, do you know what is the "minimum" requirements for a license in order for the user to be able to use the mobile App? I think it needs API and access to all objects used by the App, correct?

T.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 questions in here.

A) Where does Mobile SDK refer that it's using PhoneGap 2.3 - It used to be on the SDK release notes earlier but I don't see it updated there. In any case, I usually look at this link where it defines the external dependency for [link](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/tree/master/external/cordova-ios) to latest Cordova (PhoneGap) version. As you can see, it's 2.3

The corresponding link for Mobile SDK for Android is [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/tree/master/external/cordova).

B) For 2nd part, you simply need to have any license with API access. You don't need a separate license for Mobile SDK.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the licences you are correct that you will need api and object permissions as per your app design crud requirements. I believe the cheapest licence would be a single app platform licence although I expect there is an object limit imposed.

Although I have not tried it myself you could also look at portal/communities licences if the users are your (or your clients) customers.